# Export Whatsapp chat with replies

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app, database, chat

I'm trying to export a Whatsapp chat from an iPhone Xr with iOS 15.6 including replies to messages.

I tried to explore the `ChatStorage.sqlite` db trying to understand how does it works but it's very "messy"!

After a while, I succeded in understanding how do it works but I really can't understand how does Whatsapp store replies to messages. The only thing I noticed its that whenever a message is a reply to another message (also when a media is attached to a message, so, more generally, whenever the "graphic thing" is on top of a message), in the `ZWAMESSAGE` table under `ZMEDIAITEM` column, a value appear, which is the `Z_PK` value of an entry on the `ZWAMEDIAITEM` table. Unfortunately this last table seems to only show informations about messages with media, as every message that should be a reply, in this table has nearly every value set to `null`.

Also tried googling a bit, but I couldn't find anything.

Could you help me to understand replies in Whatsapp database please?

Comment: Wouldn’t this be better suited in a Whatsapp support communities?  While it runs on iOS, the database structure is their animal and the Whatsapp folks would be better equiped to assist

Comment: @Allan maybe you are right… Can you suggest me something?

Comment: I would start by exploring the various [Whatsapp support forums](https://www.bing.com/search?q=whatsapp%20support%20forums&pc=MOZL&form=MOZWSB). Try developer forums next.  I personally don’t use  Whatsapp so I can’t give you a definitive answer